# Magento 2.4.0 Upgrade Issue [Issue Updated]

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, magento2.4

I am upgrading Magento 2.3.5-p1 to Magento 2.4.0. I followed below steps

```
composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin=~1.0 --no-update

composer update

cp composer.json composer.json.bak

composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update

composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.0 --no-update

composer update
```

but it's showing error after run composer update command

```
root@server:/var/www/html# composer update
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information                                                       Updating dependencies (including require-dev)         
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.



Problem 1
    - magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 2.4.5 requires codeception/codeception ~2.3.4 || ~2.4.0  -> satisfiable by codeception/codeception[2.4.5, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7, 2.3.8, 2.3.9, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4].
    - magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 2.4.5 requires codeception/codeception ~2.3.4 || ~2.4.0  -> satisfiable by codeception/codeception[2.4.5, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7, 2.3.8, 2.3.9, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4].   
           
  - codeception/phpunit-wrapper 7.7.0 requires phpunit/phpunit 7.5.* -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[7.5.0, 7.5.1, 7.5.10, 7.5.11, 7.5.12, 7.5.13, 7.5.14, 7.5.15, 7.5.16, 7.5.17, 7.5.18, 7.5.19, 7.5.2, 7.5.20, 7.5.3, 7.5.4, 7.5.5, 7.5.6, 7.5.7, 7.5.8, 7.5.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - codeception/phpunit-wrapper 7.6.1 requires phpunit/phpunit >=7.1 <7.6 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.1.2, 7.1.3, 7.1.4, 7.1.5, 7.2.0, 7.2.1, 7.2.2, 7.2.3, 7.2.4, 7.2.5, 7.2.6, 7.2.7, 7.3.0, 7.3.1, 7.3.2, 7.3.3, 7.3.4, 7.3.5, 7.4.0, 7.4.1, 7.4.2, 7.4.3, 7.4.4, 7.4.5, 7.5.0, 7.5.1, 7.5.10, 7.5.11, 7.5.12, 7.5.13, 7.5.14, 7.5.15, 7.5.16, 7.5.17, 7.5.18, 7.5.19, 7.5.2, 7.5.20, 7.5.3, 7.5.4, 7.5.5, 7.5.6, 7.5.7, 7.5.8, 7.5.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

    - Installation request for magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 2.4.5 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[2.4.5].
```

Due to the limit of characters. I put my full error on this link https://newtextdocument.com/304df9aad8

I have fixed above issue by changes in composer.json file

```
"require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.5.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.16.0",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
        "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": ">=0.12.3 <=0.12.23",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~5.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4"
    },
```

But now I am getting below error.

```
Problem 1
    - magento/framework 102.0.0 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.19) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 102.0.1 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.19) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 102.0.2 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.19) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 102.0.2-p2 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.19) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.17 requires magento/framework ^102.0.3 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.3].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.0 requires magento/framework ^102.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2, 102.0.1, 102.0.0].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.1 requires magento/framework ^102.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2, 102.0.1, 102.0.0].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.10 requires magento/framework ^102.0.3 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.3].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.11 requires magento/framework ^102.0.3 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.3].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.12 requires magento/framework ^102.0.3 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.3].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.13 requires magento/framework ^102.0.3 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.3].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.14 requires magento/framework ^102.0.3 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.3].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.15 requires magento/framework ^102.0.3 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.3].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.16 requires magento/framework ^102.0.3 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.3].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.17 requires magento/framework ^102.0.3 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.3].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.2 requires magento/framework ^102.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2, 102.0.1, 102.0.0].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.2.1 requires magento/framework ^102.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2, 102.0.1, 102.0.0].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.2.2 requires magento/framework ^102.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2, 102.0.1, 102.0.0].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.2.3 requires magento/framework ^102.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2, 102.0.1, 102.0.0].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.2.4 requires magento/framework ^102.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2, 102.0.1, 102.0.0].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.3 requires magento/framework ^102.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2, 102.0.1, 102.0.0].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.4 requires magento/framework ^102.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2, 102.0.1, 102.0.0].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.5 requires magento/framework ^102.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2, 102.0.1, 102.0.0].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.6 requires magento/framework ^102.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2, 102.0.1, 102.0.0].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.7 requires magento/framework ^102.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2, 102.0.1, 102.0.0].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.8 requires magento/framework ^102.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.2-p2, 102.0.3, 102.0.2, 102.0.1, 102.0.0].
    - vnecoms/module-pdfpro 2.3.9 requires magento/framework ^102.0.3 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.5, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 102.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.5-p2, 103.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.4-p2, 103.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.5, 103.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3-p1, 103.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.4, 103.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[102.0.3, 103.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: magento/framework[103.0.0, 102.0.5].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.0 requires magento/framework 103.0.0 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[103.0.0].
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.4.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.0].
    - Installation request for vnecoms/module-pdfpro ^2.3 -> satisfiable by vnecoms/module-pdfpro[2.3.17, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.10, 2.3.11, 2.3.12, 2.3.13, 2.3.14, 2.3.15, 2.3.16, 2.3.2, 2.3.2.1, 2.3.2.2, 2.3.2.3, 2.3.2.4, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7, 2.3.8, 2.3.9].
```

I am using PHP 7.3

Comment: do you have upgraded your server?

Comment: which thing I need to upgrade in the server. I am using PHP 7.3 using.

Comment: what about  MYSQL?

Comment: I have solve this issue check updated questions @WaqarAli

Comment: Ran into similar situation when upgrading from Magento CE 2.2.6 to 2.4.1, manually updating composer.json has helped to resolve 'composer update' errors. Ran composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin=~1.1 --no-update as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best,

I have found out my Composer version was not the latest.
After updating Composer to the latest version i was able to finish the magento upgrade to 2.4.0

So simply run composer selfupdate and it will work.

Best regards...

Comment: it's showing me below error after composer update

Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/product-community-edition (locked at 2.3.5-p1, required as 2.4.0) is satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.5-p1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Answer (score 0):

Im not very experienced, so better advice from others may follow.

I would say
Check in your composer.json file

In there will be "phpunit/phpunit" listed with a version number after,

which is Version Constrain / limiting its upgrade, and causing the error message above "these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability."

So you may have to change the version number. This link may be helpful.
https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#writing-version-constraints

Comment: I have solve this issue check updated questions

Answer (score 0):

Best,

Same issue here

composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 2.5.3 requires codeception/codeception ~2.3.4 || ~2.4.0  -> satisfiable by codeception/codeception[2.4.5, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7, 2.3.8, 2.3.9, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4].
- magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 2.5.3 requires codeception/codeception ~2.3.4 || ~2.4.0  -> satisfiable by codeception/codeception[2.4.5, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7, 2.3.8, 2.3.9, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4].
- codeception/codeception 2.4.0 requires codeception/phpunit-wrapper ^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by codeception/phpunit-wrapper[6.8.1, 6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.10, 6.0.11, 6.0.12, 6.0.13, 6.0.14, 6.0.15, 6.0.16, 6.0.17, 6.0.18, 6.0.19, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.8, 6.0.9, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 6.1.2, 6.1.3, 6.5.0, 6.5.1, 6.6.0, 6.6.1, 6.7.0, 6.7.1, 6.8.0, 7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.0.2, 7.0.3, 7.0.4, 7.0.5, 7.0.6, 7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.1.2, 7.1.3, 7.1.4, 7.2.0, 7.3.0, 7.3.1, 7.3.2, 7.4.0, 7.5.0, 7.6.0, 7.6.1, 7.7.0, 7.7.1, 7.7.2, 7.8.0].

Comment: How can I solve this issue

Comment: I have solved this issue check updated questions

Comment: Can you explain in simple steps how you did solve the issue? So it is easy for (me) everyone to resolve this problem?

Comment: Check updated question

Answer (score 0):

Hi I recently upgrade successfully from Magento 2.3.3 to Magento 2.4.3
I have composer update issue too.

I resolved this by doing following these steps

if you have upgraded to composer 2x, please downgrade to composer 1x first

```
sudo composer self-update --1
```

Then run composer update using php7.1 (for magento 2.3):

```
/usr/bin/php7.1 -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer update --no-plugins
```

Then run magento upgrade command
After upgrade to magento 2.4.3, then you need upgrade composer to 2x and run this command using php7.4 for magento2.4.3:

```
/usr/bin/php7.4 -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer update --no-plugins
```

It will update successfully.